Html.Raw for RazorClassLibrary
When using a Razor Class Library project template with "Support pages and views" unchecked, it produces a project that uses *.razor files.
This project does not have a framework reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App:

The individual nuget packages for TagHelpers and Microsoft Html.Abstractions packages were marked deprecated, and those features are now in Micrposoft.AspNetCore.App.  Since this particular project template doesn't have that framework reference, those features can't be accessed.
Trying to add the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref results in an error that the project is not a DotNetPlatform project.
So I'm not sure how to access HtmlString or Html.Raw where it is necessary to output unescaped HTML.  (Note I understand the risks and how to use these features safely.)
Edit: From a project that does have a Framework ref to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, this is where HtmlHelper comes from:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\8.0.3\ref\net8.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll

You should have a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web?
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web

Thanks, I have that reference, but HtmlHelpers nor IHtmlHelper doesn't appear to be a part of that package.  When comparing to the RCL project that has pages/cshtml enabled, if I go to definition on HtmlHelper, it's coming from the framework Microsoft.AspNetCore.App reference, not the nuget package.  For example, HtmlHelper is defined in ViewFeatures under the framework reference: C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\8.0.3\ref\net8.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll

It's starting to look like this type of RCL is geared towards Blazor, and because of how that rendering pipeline works, they removed helpers intentionally.  There is an alternative MarkupString, but it isn't as flexible.
